# Argument matching parameter item cannot convert from DBNull to ListViewSubitem

Tags: vb.net, listview, isnull

```
   Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

      Me.ListView1.Items.Clear()
      Do While dr.Read

        With Me.ListView1
            .Items.Add(dr(0))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(dr.Item(1))
                .Add(dr.Item(2))
                .Add(dr.Item(3))
        End With
             End With
    Loop
    dr.Close()


   Me.Show()

    Me.ListView1.Columns.Add("Account ID", 100)
    Me.ListView1.Columns.Add("Managed by", 100)
    Me.ListView1.Columns.Add("Account Holder", 100)
    Me.ListView1.Columns.Add("Description", 100)
```

'Public Function Add(text As String )As System.Windows.Forms.Listviewitem.Listview.Subitems)As System.Windows.Forms.Listviewitem.Listview.Subitem': Argument matching parameter item cannot convert from DBNull to ListViewSubitems

Comment: Instead of (for example): `Add(dr.Item(1))` use: `Add(If(dr.IsDbNull(1), "", dr.GetString(1)))`

Comment: This error Occurs.,

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Comment: Then use `dr.GetInt32(1).ToString` instead.

Comment: I change .Add(If(dr.IsDBNull(2), "", dr.GetString(2))) to this and i get the error   .Add(If(dr.IsDBNull(1), "", GetInt32(1).ToString))
     GetInt32 is not declared. It may be inacesible due to its protection level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change to this

```
.Items.Add(dr.Item(0).ToString())
```

This will ignore null and adds blank string to item

Comment: **This is the code that works fine for me..  **
  
    setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);  
  
     Do While dr.Read  
  
                With Me.ListView1  
                    .Items.Add(dr(0))  
                    With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems  
                        .Add(dr.Item(1).ToString)  
                        .Add(dr.Item(2).ToString)  
                        .Add(dr.Item(3).ToString)  
                        .Add(dr.Item(4).ToString)  
                     
                    End With  
                End With